# Handling Fragments onBackPress inside Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have an **Activity B** that **extends** **AppCompatActivity**

I **add** (not replace) two fragments and **also** add them to the **back stack**

1. Activity B
2. Fragment 1
3. Fragment 2

```
supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .add(containerId, fragment, fragment::class.java.simpleName)
        .commit()
```

My Activity's `onBackPress()`:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
  if (fragmentBackStackCount == 1) {
      super.onBackPressed()
  } else {
      supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
  }        
}
```

I want to go back to **Activity A** but I face a blank white screen (Activity B)

How can I handle fragments back stack correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
  if (fragmentBackStackCount <= 1) {
      finish()
  }
  else {
      super.onBackPressed()
  }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open `Fragment` with `tag`

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(tag)
    .add(R.id.flContainer, fragment, tag)
    .commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

and `Activity` `onBackPressed` remove `fragment`

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val secondFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("YoursecondFragmentTagName")

    if (secondFragment != null){
       // Here remove all fragment
       if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, 
               FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
    }
    }else
        super.onBackPressed()
}
```

Hope this help you...